# can't use site when running $ wp db export

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

Using the WordPress command line interface (cli) when I export my db in preparation for a code deploy the site is not accessible when logged in for the duration of the export, which can take up to a minute. Is there a way to prevent the site from going down?

```
$ wp db export backup.sql
```